# Is there any way for iterating over different rows?I have tried row+=1 but it did not work

Tags: python, iteration, rows

I have read a CSV file using CSV.DictReader; I want to iterate over rows and compare the value of each row with some variables, I want to repeat this process until the values of row match with the values of variables. I have tried row+=1 but that did not work, can anyone suggest me another way of doing it?

```
with open(argv[1],"r") as file:
  reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
      for line in reader:
        A=int((row["AGATC"]))
        B=int((row["AATG"]))
        C=int((row["TATC"]))
      if(A==AGATCtotal and B==AATGtotal and C==TATCtotal):
        print(row["name"])[][1]
```

Comment: You should provide your code in text, rather than in image.  This way people can reproduce your result and give useful feedback easily.

Comment: @KotaMori done! can you help me with it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below would do.

```py
with open(argv[1],"r") as file:
  reader = csv.DictReader(file)
  for row in reader:
    A=int((row["AGATC"]))
    B=int((row["AATG"]))
    C=int((row["TATC"]))
    if(A==AGATCtotal and B==AATGtotal and C==TATCtotal):
      print(row["name"])
```

- `for line in reader:` is redundant, since you are already iterating over rows by the previous line.
- `if` statement is in a wrong indentation; It should be inside the for loop.  Note that Python recognizes the code block by the indentation.